# WOPI equivalent for Google docs

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, ms-wopi

MS WOPI protocol allows us to view and edit documents stored on my server within the MS Office-online environment.

I am trying find out if the similar interface is available on the google docs platform as well. What we are really looking for is to allow the users of our web application to collaborate on certain documents within our website. I would like to store these document on our server without using Google drive as a storage mechanism.

I have already explored the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) Which I think is completely tied to google drive.

Comment: We also have huge interest in using GoogleDocs in place of WOPI. It seems that with WOPI, Microsoft wants to collect a revenue stream from every end user that uses the app. We are looking for something FOSS as our solution for our customers that don't have Microsoft Office Online license. 99% of them do not. For us, asking all our end users to purchase MSFT licenses is completely out of the question.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear, but my intent was to ask @TarunGupta if you have found a solution yet? Please post here if you find a solution, and I will do the same.

Comment: We haven't been able to find any solution yet, so we have decided to continue our development using WOPI and we will wait to see if GoogleDocs provides a similar solution.

Comment: Thanks for replying @TarunGupta. WOPI works well, however it requires every one of your website visitors to have a "Office 365" license if you plan on hosting your own data. It's free (document editing, I mean) only if you just point people to the Microsoft-hosted CloudStorage. 

In short, MSFT charges you nothing if they are allowed access to (possession of) all your documents, but if you want private documents then MSFT will not allow you to use WOPI without each end user having an Office 365 license.

Comment: Do you think WOPI for Microsoft works we have had several problems with it with bugs confirmed by Microsoft which takes super long time to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at LibreOffce Online?
https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/LibreOffice_Online
https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/

The CODE manual explicitly mentions WOPI support, including document collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

[https://www.zoho.com/officeapi/ -](https://www.zoho.com/officeapi/) Zoho OfficeApi

WOPI Equivalent from Zoho allows you to integrate Zoho Editors with your site/app allowing you to create/view/edit/collaborate documents, spreadsheets and presentations.